# Explain why for an extreme point some inequalities in the constraints become equalities

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose we have a linear program
$$
\max_x c^Tx\\
\text{subject to } Ax \leq b
$$
where $\leq$ denotes pairwise inequality, i.e. $a^T_i x \leq b_i, i = 1,..., n$.

If $y$ is an extreme point, why is it that $Ay_i = b_i$ for several $i$'s?

Comment: I do assume $A$ is a matrix and $x$ a vector, the same should be true for $b$. If this is correct, what does $Ax\le b$ mean? I'm also rather sure that not everybody knows what LP is supposed to mean -- at least I don't.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose on the contrary that $y$ is an extreme point and we have $$Ay<b.$$
Let $e$ denotes the all one vector.

We can choose a small $\epsilon>0$ such that

$$A(y+\epsilon e)<b$$

and $$A(y-\epsilon e)<b.$$

We see that $y+\epsilon e$ and $y-\epsilon e$ are both in the polyhedral and we have $$y=0.5(y+\epsilon e)+0.5 (y-\epsilon e)$$ 
which contradicts that $y$ is an extreme point.

Comment: That makes sense! So does this proof imply that all inequalities become equalities? If not, for which $i$'s do equality holds?

Comment: Not necessarily unless A is a square matrix. 
In the proof, I constructed two feasible points by perturbing $y$ in the direction of $e$.
In general for my proof to work, you have to pick a direction that is orthogonal to the set of $\left\{a_i|a_i^Tx=b_i, i =1,\ldots, n\right\}$.
Relevant keyword is "basic feasible solution".

Answer (score 1):

The set of points $S$ in which the restriction holds forms a convex polytope.

Assume this polytope is finite: since the objective function is linear, the gradient is $\mathbf{c}$, which is a constant vector.

Now assume that $\mathbf{y}$ is a maximum but it is not in the border of $S$; then we can find a suitable $\epsilon>0$ such that $\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{y}+ \epsilon \mathbf{c}$ is still inside $S$, but yields a greater value of the objective function (remember $\mathbf{c}$ points in the direction of maximum increase).

Therefore, by contradiction, if $\mathbf{y}$ is a maximum it must lie in the border of $S$. That means at least one restriction will hold with equality (you could have various equalities if the maximum is at a vertex of the convex polytope)

If the polytope is not finite, actually the statement holds unchanged. You just add the possibility of not having a solution to the problem, since if $\mathbf{c}$ points in a direction that, starting from a point $\mathbf{x_0}$ inside $S$,  $\mathbf{x}+ \epsilon \mathbf{c}$ always stays inside $S$ for all $\epsilon>0$, you have no maximum.